# Do local variables in shared method work like static variable in C?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-3.5, shared

Will the list in this shared method keep its state throughout the life of the method? Or will a new list be created every time this method is called?

```
Protected Shared Function newResxNodes(ByVal newName As String, ByVal newValue As String, Optional ByVal newComment As String = "") As List(Of ResXDataNode)

    Dim newResxNodesList As List(Of ResXDataNode) = New List(Of ResXDataNode)

    Dim newResxNode As ResXDataNode = New ResXDataNode(newName, newValue)
    If newComment <> String.Empty Then
        newResxNode.Comment = newComment
    End If

    newResxNodesList.Add(newResxNode)

    Return newResxNodesList
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It does not work like static variables in C. It will be a new list for every call. If you want to retain the list and list items, create a shared class field.

Comment: I was of the understanding that shared class (and variables) are accessible by all sessions/instances of that web page. As opposed to just that user's session, which is what I was aiming for.

Comment: @dotnetN00b even a list as a static field will get destroyed and recreated on each postback. If you are trying to share a list across the webapp and not just user session, look into the application state collection. `Application["someKey"] = list` Check out this msdn page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx

Comment: Protected Shared Function foo(x as string) as Bar is the same as internal static Bar Foo(string x) in C#. In neither case are the variables scoped internal to the method retained outside of the method call itself. Also, in VB if you are creating a class with only shared methods, make it a Module and remove the Shared keyword. This will also remove the default public constructor as you should do in static classes in C#. If you want singleton objects, declare them as shared/static at the class level and consider using Lazy(Of T) to assist with single activation.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a test and it returns 3 lines.

```
Module Module1

Class b

    Public Sub New()
        Console.WriteLine("New")
    End Sub

End Class

Class a

    Public Shared Sub Test()

        Dim c As b = New b

    End Sub

End Class

Sub Main()

    a.Test()
    a.Test()
    a.Test()

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I may have missed it. But you called the method 3 times so shouldn't it return 3 lines.

Comment: I might of not understand your question correctly. Instead of created a list, I created a New B. Like your list it is being created everytime the function is called. When you asked "will a new list be created every time this method is called", then the anwser is yes.

Comment: Ah. I see. My misunderstanding. Thank you.